# Visualization of data through stripchart with different pch values (in columns)

Tags: r

May be it is simple. But I am not getting how to plot the following data using R. 
Basically the x-axis has type (i.e., *A, B, C, D* four labels). On the plot I want to represent the numbers (v1, v2, v3, v4) as points. For example, for A, on the y-axis I want to point 99, 110, 150, and 170. Moreover, I need to use different pch value for point. I tried to use stripchart but I am not sure how to assign different pch values under each of the types A, B, C, D. Please see for points (99, 110, 150, 170) of A in the below figure.

```
Data:
  type A    B   C   D
  v1  99    227 295 503      
  v2  110   440 620 970
  v3  150   600 934 1330
  v4  170   650 1012 1390
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df = read.table(header=TRUE, text="type A    B   C   D
 v1  99    227 295 503      
 v2  110   440 620 970
 v3  150   600 934 1330
 v4  170   650 1012 1390")
stripchart(df[-1], pch=c(1, 2, 3, 4), vertical=TRUE)
```

Resulting in:

[image]

## Update

Sorry, I misread the first question. Try this:

```
df2 = data.frame(t(df[-1]))
names(df2) = df$type
df2$group = rownames(df2)
library(lattice)
stripplot(v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 ~ group, data=df2, pch=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this is not what I wanted. For example, all v1 points (please see data) has same pch symbol. That is for each type we will get four different pch values.

Comment: @kkp, sorry--I read your original post quickly and misunderstood what you were looking for. I've added an update using `lattice`.